# Creating Heatmaps in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap using R.

Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
sortCC
                     Genus     Location  Number    propn
    86         Flavobacterium       CC    580 0.3081827843
    130          Algoriphagus       CC    569 0.3023379384
    88              Joostella       CC    175 0.0929861849
    215            Paracoccus       CC    122 0.0648246546
    31              Leifsonia       CC     48 0.0255047821

sortN

                  Genus   Location  Number  propn
119           Niastella        N    316 0.08205661
206         Aminobacter        N    252 0.06543755
51         Nocardioides        N    222 0.05764736
121            Niabella        N    205 0.05323293
257 Pseudorhodoferax???        N    193 0.05011685
149          Pedobacter        N    175 0.04544274
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
row.names(sortCC) <- sortCC$Genus
sortCC_matrix <- data.matrix(sortCC)
sortCC_heatmap <- heatmap(sortCC_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

I was going to generate 2 separate heatmap, but when I used the code above it looked wrong while using R.

Questions: 1)Is it possible to combine the two data set since they have the same genus, but the difference is the location and number & proportion. 2) If it is not possible to combine the two then how do I exclude the location column from the heatmap.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You say , `since they have the same genus,` but in the example you give they don't have any Genus in common? Look at `?merge` and please provide better representative data.

Comment: Sorry they are sorted based on proportion so they are not in the same order but they have the same genus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the same columns, you cand bind your data.frames and use some facets to differentiate it. Here a solution based on `ggplot2`:

```
dat <- rbind(sortCC,sortN)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(y = factor(Number),x = factor(Genus))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = propn)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) +
  facet_grid(Location~.)
```

[image]

To remove extra column , You can use `subset`:

```
subset(dat,select=-c(Location))
```

If you still want to `merge` data's by Genius, you can use do this for example:

```
sortCC <- subset(sortCC,select=-c(Location))
sortN <- subset(sortN,select=-c(Location))
merge(sortCC,sortN,by='Genus')
```

Comment: This was very useful. Is there a way using the ggplot package to make the factor(genus) spread out and readable because I am dealing with 300 genus and when I plot the genus are all bunched up. Thank you!

Comment: Switch `aes(y = factor(Number),x = factor(Genus))` to `aes(x = factor(Number),y = factor(Genus))` and add `+ facet_grid(Location~., scales = "free", space = "free")` to remove empty levels per grid.

Comment: Thank You! @agstudy I want to delete the factor(Genus) from the heatmap, but when I do ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(Genus))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = propn)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) +
  facet_grid(Location~.)                                             the R console says "Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing" I was wondering why? And how can I make the console not give me that message.